# Redux: Unsubscribing a listener inside that listener is not working

Tags: javascript, redux, listener

I have a listener function that listens to store changes.

```js
unsub = store.subscribe(gameListener);
```

The `gameListener` function looks like this:

```js
const gameListener = () => {
  // getting gameState from store...

  if (gameState.hasGameStarted) {
    startGame();
    unsub();
  }
}
```

The listener is not getting unsubscribed even though I'm calling the `unsub` method. The thing is the when I put `unsub()` outside the `if` statement, it's working. Any idea why this happens?

Note that the condition will become `true` at some point, and I've verified that the control goes inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `unsubscribe` function is only returned after you register `gameListener` as a subscriber, you can't define `gameListener` with `unsub()` inside, and if you redefine it after subscribing it's not the same function.

You can, however, define an external object, let's call it `ref` (taking a page from react hooks), use it inside the `gameListener` function, and update the ref's `unsub` function after it's created.

```
const ref = {};

const gameListener = () => {
  // getting gameState from store...

  if (gameState.hasGameStarted) {
    startGame();
    ref.unsub();
  }
};

const unsub = store.subscribe(gameListener);

ref.unsub = unsub;
```